# Issue in caching using coffeescript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've this script

```
class Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View

    div: $('#input')

    initialize: ->

       console.log @div.val()
```

As you can see this is a backbone's view.

I would like to cache `$('#div')` into a variable and call it. See the `console.log @div.val()`.

But this seems  not working..

Using normal javascript I'd write something like this:

```
var ToDoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    div : $('#input'),
    initialize: function(){
         console.log(this.div.val());
    }
})
```

And this is working fine. Where I'm going wrong with coffeescript?

Comment: Your indenting looks wrong for the coffeescript version.

Comment: you're rigth, but In the source code the indention is ok. This is not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences in how Coffeescript classes work and Backbone's extend mechanism work, which could be the issue you are running into. But I'm guessing that is not the issue here. There could be differences in exactly when and where you are running this code as well. If you put the javascript code in the same place where you are executing your coffeescript code, does it then work ok? And on a related note, what *exacly* is the problem, i.e. what error messages are you getting? Is @div initialized at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the `$("#input")` element hasn't been loaded at the moment your code runs.

The problem with caching the value in the class is that the class is most likely being defined outside the jQuery.ready callback (before the DOM has finished loading) so at the moment your class sets `$("#input")` as `@div` jQuery doesn't actually find that element.

You could set `@div` in the `initialize` function since that will most likely be called after the DOM has loaded.